# How do you pass JWT to service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4, openid-connect

In a demo 'client' website setup with [code authorization flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/regular-web-app-login-flow) I receive a JWT asserting my user's identity when they successfully login from my own local identity provider (IdentityServer4). This is stored as a cookie that looks like this (shortened it with ...):

> ai_user=kFgLY|2018-12-11T15:40:11.940Z; AMCV_700CFDC5570CBFE67F000101%40AdobeOrg=2121618341%7CMCIDTS%7...ywuxL1PHcA

The client site is configured like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "cookie";
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = "cookie";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("cookie")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5005";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        options.ClientId = "test_pkce_client";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.ResponseMode = "form_post";
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-test";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context => HandleRedirectToIDP(context);

        options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context => HandleCodeReceived(context);

    });
```

When a user authenticates though, I want to capture that JWT. When I make requests to my downstream web services, I want to pass that JWT along, so they can (independently) validate the user's authentication and also independently query if that user should have permission to perform a given API action. I also want my web services to accept the [client credentials grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/client-credentials) for machine-to-machine authentication, in cases where that is necessary.

Using identityserver4 and .NET Core, how can I accomplish this? How can I make my [Authorize] annotation inside my web service distinguish between the two flows and gracefully handle this? In my demo web service, I have the client credentials grant working fine:

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication("token", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5005";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ApiName = "SomeAPI";
                    options.ApiSecret = "secret";
                });
```

1) In my service, how can I add a second authentication method that reads in a JWT from my client? Is it just as simple as **AddJwtBearer()** in the startup?
2) In my 'client', how can I capture and send (in order to retain) my authorized user's JWT to other services?

I thought this wouldn't work, but just to show an attempted effort of what I mean, from my 'client' website in an [Authorize]'d controller I have attempted on my client

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult SecurePage()
{
            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://localhost:3721/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", Request.Headers["Cookie"].First());

            var apiTask = client.GetAsync("Test");
            apiTask.Wait();
            string response = apiTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This obviously 401's from my service.

### UPDATE

After receiving some aid from d_f, I translated my shoddy idea above to this:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> SecurePage()
{
string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("cookie", "access_token");
string idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("cookie", "id_token");

var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://localhost:3721/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var apiTask = client.GetAsync("Test");
apiTask.Wait();

string response = apiTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The trick is to treat the user's accessToken like it's a client credentials grant token. Also, make sure AddOpenIdConnect in your client startup is **options.SaveTokens = true;** and that your ResponseType is **options.ResponseType = "code id_token";** This will allow an API which has **.AddIdentityServerAuthentication("token", options =>** to read your request and authenticate it against the IDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks, you mess up different things. In your **API** `.AddIdentityServerAuthentication()` [is just a decorator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation) over  `AddJwtBearer()`, so for your case (with external call of a method protected with `[Authorize]`) it already works. I guess you always use JWT and added a secret in order to be able to request a new token directly from API, and not for reference token validation? In that case you need to involve [TokenClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2/blob/master/samples/HttpClientFactorySample/WebApplication1/TokenClient.cs).
In your **client** you just need to call `SetBearerToken(apiAccessToken)` on your `HttpClient` instance, instead of sending a cookie, but you have to request and persist that token first. [This fresh article](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/14/automatic-oauth-2-0-token-management-in-asp-net-core/) contains a link to a [working example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Clients/src/MvcHybridAutomaticRefresh)

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. I am going to update my answer with what I discovered based on your links.